# Is there a desktop weather app?

Tags: software-recommendation, weather

Is there any weather app that works with Ubuntu 12.04?

I tried many of them including the screenlets.

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Give up on a weather widget. Set a bookmark for your favorite weather site in Firefox and make do with that. I'm an electrical engineer, so not exactly lacking in PC skills. I messed around for a couple of hours trying to find and install various weather widgets. I give up. I like Ubuntu a lot, but no distro is perfect, and Ubuntu seems hostile to weather widgets. In PCLinuxOS, I had the choice of about four of them, and they were all simple one click installations to the panel. I also miss the dictionary widget. I used these two widgets all the time. The Ubuntu Widget Nazi says, "NO WIDGETS F

Answer (score 50):

Here are some variants you may like:

## First Way: city lens

---

![this is that "weather lens"][1]

---

to install type this in terminal(to start <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-utilities unity-scope-cities
```

---

## Second Way: weather indicator

---
![weather applet indicator][4]
---
to install weather applet indicator write in terminal(to start <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-weather
```

or click this button
[image: Download]

---

## Third Way: My Weather Indicator

---
![My weather indicator][7]
---
to install my weather indicator type in terminal(to start <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

---

## Fourth Way: Stormcloud

### (**deprecated**)

### [image: Stormcloud]

Paid Application ($2.99), [available at developers' website](http://getstormcloud.com/)

---

## For gnome shell users

---
Here we have one amazing extension for gnome shell called **Weather** or something like that. Here is screenshot:

---

### [image: screenshot]

So to install this just move on [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/613/weather/) and click that switch-i like thing on the right to turn it on, and it will ask you do you want to install it. Just say yes. Add your cities and you have another awesome weather app for **gnome**!

---

## Alternative Way: HTC-style Weather Clock

---
![HTC-style coool weather clock][12]
---
for this just read from [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/htc-weather-clock-widget-ubuntu)

Comment: How to add the above DOWNLOAD FOR UBUNTU icon while posting.I know it is not a right way to ask question.

Comment: Sorry @tijybba, but i can't understand what you wrote. Did you want to know how i add button???

Comment: Yes exactly , sorry for bad communication.

Comment: Now will upload to youtube the video tutorial. please wait for 5-7 mins @tijybba

Comment: uploaded to youtube: @tijybba link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXB3cu7i2Sg

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install stormcloud' doesn't work.

Comment: @owl to make it work, u need to add rep, have you did that?

Comment: @geoh I did it. It does not work anymore. You can test it.

Comment: @owl ha ha, now its non free, its about $3
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/stormcloud/

Comment: lucky those who installed stormcloud before the price came in.

Comment: @owl, not so, i installed, but can't run now :/

Comment: `unity-scope-cities` isn't in the repos..  At least not now..

Comment: ah .. thanks for telling @Seth, repo must be added

Answer (score 9):

**Note**: The software in this answer does not work anymore due to Yahoo Weather API changes.

---

There's a fork of Stormcloud for those who don't want to pay.

> Typhoon is a free and open source weather application. It is based on Stormcloud 1.1 ,however without the bells and whistles. It is and always will be free. We have not included features like multiple locations due to no one can live in more than one places in a specific time(except electrons!). If you want to check the weather of any other location, you have to change the location. Also, we have not included 'chameleonic background' as it would make the app resource hungry. It is now a couple of mbs but 'chameleonic background' would make it around 300 mb.

To install Typhoon, start terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, then run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/typhoon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install typhoon
```

Source: https://launchpad.net/typhoon

Homepage & Installation: http://gettyphoon.tk/

Comment: Just great. Is it possible to extend it to show more info, e.g. Sunset/Sunrise?

Answer (score 6):

## wttr.in

Here is a one-liner that is run from the command line. 
Open up a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the following command:

```
curl -s wttr.in/<your location>
```

This makes a call to the `wttr.in` website based on your specified location. The default settings provides the current weather along with a three day forecast. In my case, I use the following command:

```
curl -s wttr.in/bothell
```

This results in the following output:

[image: url]

Generally, I do not need an entire three day forecast, and I also wanted the current date and time displayed, so I wrapped this in a tiny shell script, called `weather.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
date
curl -s wttr.in/bothell | head -7
```

This gives me the following output to the console:

```
Tue Aug 30 23:39:31 PDT 2016
Weather for City: Bothell, United States of America
 \   /     Clear 
  .-.      62 °F          
―(   ) ―   ↖ 8 mph        
  `-’      9 mi           
 /   \     0.0 in
```

If you are interested in the back-end code, it can be found at https://github.com/chubin/wttr.in
I found the original command on [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/17709/nice-weather-forecast-on-your-shell).

Answer (score 1):

> Indicator-Weather is a fully featured weather notification applet for use on the GNOME
>   panel. Current weather status is displayed directly on your panel and
>   detailed forecasts are no more than a click away. Implemented using
>   the Indicator Applet API.

<sup>Source: https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator</sup>

[Click to download weather-indicator source package](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator)

[Click here to install the 32-bit.deb package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-weather/11.11.28-0ubuntu1/+build/3108926/+files/indicator-weather_11.11.28-0ubuntu1_all.deb)

I have installed, and it works excellently.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-weather` works fine under LXDE (Lubuntu). I installed it in the Application Launch Bar.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-weather
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to install weather indicator :

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-weather
```

Comment: warning: indicator-weather crashes and won't be fixed. the project is officially dead.