# Can't find a Software Center Badge?

Tags: software-center

I just published my game "Plush" to the software center, and I want to have a badge on my website that links to the web listing, but based on my searches, software center doesn't seem to have a "Badge" (for example, here's google play's: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/badges.html )

Am I just missing it?  If there really isn't one, I guess I just use an Ubuntu logo?

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen something like this as apturl-link (something like `apt://cowsay`). I've never seen any USC badge and I don't think it exists.

Edit: Just found this Ask Ubuntu question. See first answer->Weather indicator. I realised I've seen it before:

[Is there a desktop weather app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149707/is-there-a-desktop-weather-app)